# Oracle 18c - getting error ORA-29541 migrating java source code from oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle12c, oracle18c

After migrating to Oracle 18c from Oracle 12c, the following java source code is not working because SQLJ is incompatible with our 18c migration. What is the best way to rewrite Oracle Java code to call our db packages in 18c?

A DBA has told us the issue could be with the `#sql` and the code needs to be rewritten but I am no java expert and don't know how extensive the rewrite needs to be. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MoveFile
{
    public static void getFileList(String directory_source , String directory_target ) throws SQLException
    {
        File path = new File(directory_source);
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File path, String name) {
                return !name.startsWith(".");
            }
        };
        String[] list = path.list(filter);
        String element;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            element = list[i];
            #sql { --this seems to be the issue since the compiler says invalid character "#"
                call my_user.my_package(:directory_source, :directory_target, :element)
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the error message we get:

```
`ORA-29541: class MY_USER.MoveFile could not be resolved`
```

This is used created in a procedure in the following package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE UTIL_OS AS

    FUNCTION run_cmd(p_cmd IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
      LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'ExecuteOSCommand.runThis(java.lang.String) return integer';

    PROCEDURE MoveFile (in_file_path IN VARCHAR2) IS
          LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'DirectoryListMove.getList(java.lang.String,java.lang.String )';

END;
```

/

This was my attempt which compiled successfully (at this time i'm just trying to perform ANY database operation to see if a connection is at least possible):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED MoveFile AS
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

//import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class DirectoryListMove
{
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";  
   static final String DB_URL = ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:myport/myservicename");

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "my_user";
   static final String PASS = "my_password";

public static void getList(String directory_source , String directory_target ) throws SQLException
{
   File path = new File(directory_source);
   FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File path, String name) {
        return !name.startsWith(".");
    }
};
   Connection conn = null;

      try {
           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            //STEP 4: Execute a query

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

           //attempt to execute a working DML statement
            String query = " insert into my_table values ('99','Test',9,'N')";
          statement.executeUpdate(query);

            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           // . . .
        }
        finally {
          //  . . .
        }
}
};
```

Then I executed the procedure:

```
BEGIN
            UTIL_OS.MoveFile
                (
                    '/myFile/Path'
                );
end;
/
```

Since we are currently attempting to just insert a record into the database table, the input parameter is irrelevant to this question. The record was not inserted, leading me to believe there is an issue with the java code.

Comment: What does "not working anymore" mean? How was that code compiled before? You *are* still using SQLJ when compiling the code, right?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please: what should mean "not working"?

Comment: Hi @Andreas , pls see the error message I added for reference to "not working".

Comment: Oh, you're talking about a Java class installed into the database, not a normal java class *using* the database? Perhaps you should clarify that. --- Also, as far as I know, the `#sql` syntax is something **SQLJ** does, and I see no mention of SQLJ in your question. It is certainly not something Java does natively.

Comment: Maybe this is related - [Starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2), Oracle does not support server-side SQLJ code.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jsqlj/changes-this-release-oracle-sqlj-developers-guide.html).

Comment: @Andreas yes, java class installed into the database. Please see more edits in my post.

Comment: I have the solution, but this post needs to be reopened so as to allow me to answer the question. It may be very helpful to others.